# check if SACL is enabled for a folder using cpp

Tags: c++, winapi, acl

I am working on a cpp program that sets the SACL properties for a given folder.
I am performing that by

- first reading the existing SACL of the folder using GetNamedSecurityInfo() function
- Then creating 2 Explicit_Access objects for the Everyone group for full control except read with both CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE and OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE
- Then setting the ExplicitAccess into the sacl object using the SetEntriesInAcl() function
- finally set the new SACL into the folder using the SetNamedSecurityINfo() function

My problem is that the program does not check whether the SACL is already set or not
I tried to get the AccessRights for the Everyone group using the GetAuditedPermissionsFromAcl() function but the resulting access rights, both success and failure does not match with the DWORD value which I used when creating the ExplicitAccess objects, and with just the AccessRights I can't check whether the subfolders and files inherit the SACL or not

I also tried to read the Explicit_Access object from the sacl using the GetExplicitEntriesFromAcl() function but I don't how to traverse through the array of the explicit entries and to check for them

Is there any simple way to check whether the SACL policies are enabled for a folder?

Comment: This looks like a privileged operation. Maybe running with [special privileges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secbp/running-with-special-privileges) could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <AccCtrl.h>
#include <AclAPI.h>
#include <string>
#include <sddl.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

static PSTR WINAPI SIDToName(PSID lpSID);

static BOOL UpProcessPriority() {
    HANDLE h_token_handle = nullptr;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES token_privileges;
    BOOL result = FALSE;

    result =
        OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(),
            static_cast<unsigned>(TOKEN_QUERY) |
            static_cast<unsigned>(TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES),
            &h_token_handle);

    if (result != 0) {
        result = LookupPrivilegeValueW(nullptr, SE_SECURITY_NAME,
            &token_privileges.Privileges[0].Luid);
        if (result != 0) {
            token_privileges.PrivilegeCount = 1;
            token_privileges.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

            result = AdjustTokenPrivileges(
                h_token_handle, FALSE, &token_privileges, 0, nullptr, nullptr);
        }
    }

    if (h_token_handle != nullptr) {
        CloseHandle(h_token_handle);
    }
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    UpProcessPriority();
    SECURITY_INFORMATION requestedInfo = DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSecDes = NULL; DWORD secSize = 0;
    /*CHAR filePath[MAX_PATH] = "C:\\Program Files\\zsw";*/
    CHAR filePath[MAX_PATH] = "C:\\Program Files\\";
    if (!GetFileSecurityA(filePath, requestedInfo, pSecDes, secSize, &secSize))
    {
        pSecDes = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, secSize);
        if (!GetFileSecurityA(filePath, requestedInfo, pSecDes, secSize, &secSize)) {
            std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_CONTROL pControl; DWORD revision;
    if (GetSecurityDescriptorControl(pSecDes, &pControl, &revision))
    {
        if ((pControl & SE_DACL_PROTECTED) == SE_DACL_PROTECTED) {
            std::cout << "DACL: can not use, disable " << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "DACL: can use, enable" << std::endl;
        }

        if ((pControl & SE_SACL_PROTECTED) == SE_SACL_PROTECTED) {
            std::cout << "SACL: can not use, disable" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "SACL: can use, enable" << std::endl;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}

PSTR WINAPI SIDToName(PSID lpSID)
{
    LPSTR userName = NULL; LPSTR domainName = NULL; DWORD nameSize = 0; DWORD domainSize = 0; SID_NAME_USE peUse;
    if (!LookupAccountSidA(NULL, lpSID, userName, &nameSize, domainName, &domainSize, &peUse))
    {
        userName = (LPSTR)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, nameSize);
        domainName = (LPSTR)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, domainSize);
        if (!LookupAccountSidA(NULL, lpSID, userName, &nameSize, domainName, &domainSize, &peUse))
            std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
    }
    return userName;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).